# How to make condition for Explicit Waits?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'd like to create a condition for the element.

For example, if an element is missing, a timeout error occurs. Then, let's try another function (select_getPage_2) as follows:

It's the code I think it is.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "CLASS NAME")))

# CASE A: find element 
items = select_getPage_1(driver)
for item in items:
    record = get_result_flipkart(item)
    if record:
        test1_records.append(record)
       
# CASE B: NOT find element 
items = select_getPage_2(driver)
for item in items:
    record = get_result_flipkart(item)
    if record:
        test2_records.append(record)
```

How to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a timeout error occurs raise when initialization `element` ?,so condition depend on that.

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "CLASS NAME")))
    items = select_getPage_1(driver)
except e: 
    items = select_getPage_2(driver)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question seems Unclean to me but, I suggest add `try..except..finally` block to your code!

```
try:
  # catch up on your desire output
except EX1:
  # do optimal handling in case of EX1 occurred and so on for EX2,3...
finally:
  # do your last solution
```